# Google-App-Script base64 vs javascript base64 decode

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Please, help with GoogleApps Script Base 64 Decode

-- Google Apps Script

```
  var tmp_base64 = "EXezAAA=";
  var byte_base64 = Utilities.base64Decode(tmp_base64);

  return ContentService.createTextOutput('\''+ tmp_base64 + '\' => \''+byte_base64 +'\'' );
```

return : 'EXezAAA=' => '17,119,-77,0,0'

-- javascript

```
function _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
    var len = binary_string.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes;
}
_base64ToArrayBuffer('EXezAAA=');
```

return : Uint8Array(5) [ 17, 119, 179, 0, 0 ]

correctly converted javascript,
but why does Google Apps Script convert to wrong bytes?

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the document of "Uint8Array" is seen, it says as follows. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array)

> The Uint8Array typed array represents an array of 8-bit unsigned integers.

By this, your `_base64ToArrayBuffer` returns `[17, 119, 179, 0, 0]`.

On the other hand, at Google Apps Script, the byte array uses "twos-complement 8-bit signed integers" as the default. By this, `Utilities.base64Decode("EXezAAA=")` returns `[17, 119, -77, 0, 0]`.

This is the reason for your current situation.

For example, when you want to retrieve the same value, in Javascript, please modify it as follows.

#### From:

```
var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
```

#### To:

```
var bytes = new Int8Array(len);
```

By this, your `_base64ToArrayBuffer` returns `[17, 119, -77, 0, 0]`.

When you want to retrieve the value of `[17, 119, 179, 0, 0]` at Google Apps Script, please modify it as follows.

#### From:

```
var byte_base64 = Utilities.base64Decode(tmp_base64);
```

#### To:

```
var byte_base64 = [...Uint8Array.from(Utilities.base64Decode(tmp_base64))];
```

By this, your `_base64ToArrayBuffer` returns `[17, 119, 179, 0, 0]`.

#### References:

- [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array)
- [Int8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int8Array)

  - When the document of "Int8Array" is seen, it says as follows. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int8Array)

  > The Int8Array typed array represents an array of twos-complement 8-bit signed integers.

Comment: a very clear answer.